# arcgis flex api

Tags: arcgis

I am new to flex and arcgis. I find this really confusing. I will try to explain my problem. I have installed arcgis server on my system and also have flex builder3 and arc_gis api for flex installed. There are some maps (.mxd files) created in arc map. When i tried to create a web application using arcserver it is taking lot of time to run in the browser. How can the flex api help me to run them faster.

Answer (score 2):

Its not clear to me what are you trying to ask but Im going to try and answer anyway.

if by run you meant execute, apps made with the arcgis server manager are very javascript heavy, so maybe your pc is having a hard time executing code. Flash is not lightweight either, but its faster to use on a browser to scroll maps, zoom, etc.

If by run you meant load, then flash loads slower, a flex application is usually heavier than the default arcgis server app. Also some code is server side, but in flex only map querys are serverside.

And if by run you meant tiles take forever to load, you may be using dynamic layers. You should try to use cached tiles.

Another thing is that you must code a flex app, but a java/.net app is created with the arcgis server manager if you want.

Maybe if you write more especifically what are you trying to do I can help you better.